# What makes detection of optimized-away memory clearing non-trivial?

Tags: attack-prevention, data-leakage, c, detection, automated-testing

In [this 35C3 talk](https://media.ccc.de/v/35c3-9788-memsad), it is said that while it is possible to manually inspect whether a package optimizes away `memset()` that clears sensitive memory, doing it automatically would be challenging. Assuming that the binary is compiled with `-ggdb` which IIRC contains source-to-binary mapping, what makes such detection difficult?

Comment: Have you tried contacting the author of the talk? If the talk is unclear, that would be the person to ask. Also, why would your assumption necessarily be true?

Comment: @EricLippert it's not necessarily true - which is why I'm asking about it.

Comment: What I'm getting at is that your assumption makes it sound like the question is "if we assume that detecting this is easy, what makes it hard?"  Nothing; we've assumed that it's easy. I don't understand why you've made the assumption.